# Mesh generation in Fenics python

Tags: python

I how can I generate the following mesh in Fenics. My domain is [-1,1]*[-1,1]. I tried the following

```
mesh = Rectangle(-1,-1,1,1)
```

but this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is done with Points now:

```
from dolfin import*
mesh_density = 10   
p1 = Point(0,0)
p2 = Point(1,1)
mesh = RectangleMesh(p1,p2,mesh_density,mesh_density)
```

Assuming you use Fenics 1.6

Answer (score -2):

You have to look for the command [`RectangleMesh`](http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/dolfin/dev/python/programmers-reference/cpp/mesh/RectangleMesh.html).